# How to read JSON Value in ASP.NET Core controller?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

How can I get value of `request_id` from the JSON inside my ASP.NET Core controller ?

```
{
    "request_id": "5nRJwCgt95yfmq9qVPrzei16568823342584",
    "number": "90001000000",
    "price": 0.028
}
```

I need to assign value of `request_id` to string `ReqID`.

My controller code is as follows

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestAuthenticate() 
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.mysmsprovider.com/v1/verify");
    var request = new RestRequest("",Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "api_secret=123M&api_key=84545&code_length=4&from=NBL&to=90000001", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    return Ok(response.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC already handles this. Put the model as a param to the action method.

For example, create a model the includes the data you are interested in receiving with properties matching the JSON fields:

```
public class MyData {
    public string request_id {get;set;}
}
```

And the controller

```
public class MyController {
    public Result MyActionMethod(MyData myData) {
        // now myData.request_id contains 5nRJwCgt95yfmq9qVPrzei16568823342584
        // you can use it/assign it to whatever you want
        var ReqID = myData.request_id;
    }
}
```

Edit:

If you already have the JSON as a string, you can manually deserialize it into an object as follows:

```
var myData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
// now myData.request_id will be the value you expect.
var ReqID = myData.request_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, please see my code added to question which returns json response

Comment: @Sulfy I updated my answer to include the case where you handle JSON that you obtain from whatever source (REST API call in your case)

Answer (score 2):

you have to parse response.Content

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string ReqID= JObject.Parse(response.Content)["request_id"].ToString();
```